# Install R on Debian 8.2 jessie

Tags: r, debian

I can't install R on Debian 8.2 jessie

- to /etc/apt/sources.list add http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/debian jessie-cran3
- apt-get update
- apt-get install r-base r-base-dev

The following packages have unmet dependencies:....

[image]

Comment: the output already tells you what are the problems. First install the unmet dependencies and then try again installing `R`.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks...I resolved this...

```
/etc/apt/source.list .. 
deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian jessie main
apt-get install r-base r-base-dev
```

Comment: Which versions of R you get by this method? - - Apt-get has by default only 3.1.1, so not the latest.

Comment: @LéoLéopoldHertz준영 how can I install the latest R in Debian? I have problems to install RCurl and apparently caused by this old 3.1.1 version of R (speculating).